# is there a way to add carousel for nativescript-angular app?

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there a way to add carousel to Nativescript-angular app?

I tried doing it with [nativescript-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-carousel),but gradle build is failing when I tried to add dependencies of [pageIndicatorView](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView).

My Project info is:

nativescript: 3.4.0

tns-android: 3.4.0

Angular: 5.0.5

Comment: Got It after giving a new build,thanks @Nick lliev

Comment: There is no need to add pageIndicatorView

Answer (score 0):

As logged in the plugin README

> (Angular) Only static slides work, the dynamic ones with binding do
>   not (for now).

Comment: I don't need dynamic, just static is fine for me, but adding the pageIndicatorView plugin to build.gradle is not throwing errors.my app have appcompact-v7. Can you please look into it.